# Setting intent-filter for two activities in AndroidManifest.xml, neither gets its intents. What have I done wrong?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have multiple activities in my app, and I wish for different intents to reach each one.  I've defined them in AndroidManifest.xml like so:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.dish.samdroid.PickTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.dish.samdroid.TestTestTest"
        android:label="TestTestTest"
        android:parentActivityName=".PickTestActivity"  >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PickTestActivity" />

        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
            <data android:scheme="craig" /> 
        </intent-filter> 

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.dish.samdroid.LoginWithBrowser"
        android:label="LoginWithBrowser"
        android:parentActivityName=".PickTestActivity"  >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PickTestActivity" />

        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
            <data android:scheme="samdroid" /> 
        </intent-filter> 

    </activity>
```

But URLs like craig://hello don't reach TestTestTest and samdroid://login doesn't reach LoginWithBrowser.  The intents worked when I only had one activity in my app.  Is it because the activities are no longer MAIN, or because they have parent activity, or is something else amiss?

How would I specify that those two activities get those two urls?

Comment: what do you mean by "those activities get those urls" ?? I don't understand your issue

Comment: As I understand it, and my first program did this, if I put android:scheme="muggle" into an intent-filter data element, then muggle://dudley.dursley typed into a browser will be directed to my activity.  That's the behavior I'm looking to get: browser (or webview, it also worked) links and redirects getting routed to my activities.  Since I put multiple activities into my app, it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? Have you checked the logcat? Don't filter the logcat because you might miss something valuable/useful/important. See what logs are written when you use the schemes in the browser.